# Hitting redis server with redis hash using JMeter (using redis-dataset plugin)

Tags: redis, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a redis server running and I wanted to use JMeter to get the benchmarks and to find in how much time it hits 20K transactions per second. I have a hash setup. How should I go about querying it. I have put one of the keys as `redis key` and have put one of the `fields` of the hash as `variable name`.

If I use `constant throughput timer`, what should I enter in the `name` field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get a solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to use Constant Throughput Timer and your target it to get 20k requests per second load you need to configure it as follows:

- Target Throughput: `1200000` (20k per second * 60 seconds in minute)
- Calculate Throughput based on: `all active threads`

See [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) article for more details.

Few more recommendations:

1. Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** the threads so make sure you have enough virtual users on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level
2. Constant Throughput Timer is accurate enough on "minute" level, so make sure your test lasts long enough so the timer will be correctly applied. Also consider reasonable ramp-up period.
3. Some people find [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) easier to use
4. 20k+ concurrent threads is normally something you cannot achieve using single machine so it is likely you'll need to consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) when multiple JMeter instances act as a cluster.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot! Also, how should I go about querying the redis server. I have a hash with multiple fields in my redis table.